# Who owns a foster animal?

Tags: halacha, animals

In animal foster care, the shelter provides everything including food. You are required to take care of the animal (feed, walks, train…). Are you or the shelter considered the owner and by extension is milk/meat mixture food an issue?

To me it makes sense that the shelter is the owner and you are something like a contractor as you have many responsibilities towards them to including they may at any moment take the animal away.

Comment: Probably depends on the specifics of the contracts at each such place

Comment: meat/milk mixture food would be an issue regardless if you are the owner. Feeding it to a stray dog is also no good. But as long as you are responsible for feeding it I would assume that the laws of "owner" would apply to you.